# Recursive function only returning first result

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a file upload feature using native DnD and the browser API.

I have to functions like so:

```
export function buildFileTree(allObjects) {
  let fileTree = {}

  allObjects.forEach((item, index) => {
    traverseFileTree(fileTree, null, item)
  })

  return fileTree
}

export function traverseFileTree(fileTree, parent = null, item) {

  let parentId = !!parent ? fileTree[parent].id : parent

  if (item.isFile) {

    item.file(file => {
      fileTree[item.fullPath] = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        name: item.name,
        parent_id: parentId,
        file: item
      }
    })

  }

  if (item.isDirectory) {


    fileTree[item.fullPath] = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: item.name,
      is_directory: true,
      parent_id: parentId,
      file: null
    }

    let dirReader = item.createReader()
    dirReader.readEntries(entries => {
      entries.forEach((entry, index) => {
        traverseFileTree(fileTree, item.fullPath, entry)
      })
    })
  }

}
```

Which I use like so, and I'm getting very weird results, when I `console.log` the object, it shows the correct data, but when I try to stringify it, access any other attributes, or iterate over it; it's only showing the first result.

```
const handleUploadDrop = (files) => {
  const finalFiles = buildFileTree(files)

  console.log(finalFiles) // This shows the correct data
  console.log(JSON.stringify(finalFiles)) // This only shows 1 item!!!
  console.log(Object.keys(finalFiles).length) // This prints 1
}
```

I'm very confused by this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting values in `fileTree` by writing to the same keys. The first write should be `fileTree[file.fullPath]` or something similar; not `item.fullPath` (no familiar with the file API).

Comment: `file` doesn't have a `fullPath` property only `item` does, and even if make each key unique `fileTree[uuidv4()]` I get the same strange behavior, so I don't think the tree is being overwritten.